# How can I ask the user if they'd like to save their username/password like Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, form-submit, web-deployment

I'm making a chrome extension that will act as a password manager similar to Chrome's but with some different functionality.

When the user submits the log in form, my extension is able to intercept the submit and grab the username and password. Now I'd like to display a pop-up asking the user if they'd like to save the password or not.

If it's possible to display my own custom HTML on top of whatever page exists, it would disappear since the page is reloading. So should I store the data in a session variable and each time the page loads, check if it has something?

I'd like to avoid just opening up another window, it looks sloppy. Is there a better way to grab the form data and use if after the page has been loaded after the submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a combination of event and content scripts.

Register content script with manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "js": [ "/util/jquery.js", "main.js"],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "run_at": "document_start",    
}],
```

The content script listens for a form to be submitted

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log('submit');
  var formData = findFormData($this); //function searches form for username/password

  //Send message to background page with user/pass data
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting:'form_submit', data:formData}, function(){ /*if needed */ });

});
```

Create register the background script with the manifest (use persistent=false to make the background script an "event" script). We'll also need the following permissions

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["/background/background.js"],
  "persistent" : false
},
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "storage",
  "webNavigation"
]
```

Finally, we add the message listener into the background page

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender,     sendResponse) {
switch (request.greeting) {
  case 'form_submit':
    var data = request.data;
    console.log('We Have Data!', request.data);

    //We want to display the prompt when this page loads, so add listener
    chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener( function askUser(details) {

      //Create prompt here!

      //remove the onCompleted listener so it doesn't appear when navigating again
      chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(askUser);
    });

    sendResponse({farewell: "success"});

    break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That's tricky ...

I don't use chrome extensions themselves, but I do write GreaseMonkey extensions which are similar.

First, let me say this is a bad idea... there are some security concerns here that are VERY significant, but I'll answer how you go into it.

The first step is telling when a page load just-so-happens to follow a submit (as opposed to being opened via a book mark or link or open in new tab).

The only way I know to do this is to link into the `window.name` property, which persists between page loads.

To say this is hacky would be true.  TO say its fragile would be even more true.  It may even suddenly quit working under some browsers.

But, its the only way I know of.

So.. your steps are.

1. Determine if this is a form worth saving.
2. Hook into the `form.submit` and save the URL, the user name and password off.  If the page uses ajax or hooks onto `form.submit` itself, all bets are off.
3. Set a flag in `window.name`
4. Let the page reload
5. See if the page logged in.  Most likely by seeing if there is a `password` field on the page.
6. See if your flag in `window.name` is there -- this this page was loaded from a login.
7. Clear the window.name flag
8. If no password field, pop up a floating div asking to save the info.
9. Save it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Not sure if your answer is my best option or not, but I'll definitely consider it. I'd also like to know what security concerns you have. The extension also stores the passwords in a database, not locally, if that makes a difference.

Comment: That makes a difference and is even worse .. you'd be storing plain text passwords in a spot that may be compromised.  I.. *reallllly* recommend against going down this route.

Comment: How do other password managers do it then? I haven't implemented this part yet, but there would be some form of encryption involved. If there's no safe way to store their passwords, then this project will just remain a learning experience and won't go live. So don't worry haha.